# JavaScript object has key with specific regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, key, javascript-objects

How to find whether a JavaScript object has key with specific regex pattern ? For example, in the below object, how to find whether it contains a key containing the word "Address"?

```
var obj = {Address_Line1 : "XXX", Address_Line2 :"YYY", Name : "ZZZ"};
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).toString().indexOf('Address') !== -1`

Comment: What is your issue? Do you need to know how to get the keys of an object? Do you need to know how to loop across them? Do you need to know how to find if one string is contained in another?

Comment: Not sure if the answer I provided is what he wants, but it's what he is currently asking for.  @Tushar's solution is better for the exact spec, but if OP ever needs to check each key with a regex, my solution might cover that more easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure - you can do this with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), like so:

```js
var obj = {Address_Line1 : "XXX", Address_Line2 :"YYY", Name : "ZZZ"};

var hasKeyRegex = Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
  return /Address/.test(key);
});

console.log(hasKeyRegex);
```

`hasKeyRegex` will be `true` if the object has a key containing `Address`, and `false` if not.

Comment: Why the `^` at the beginning, since the spec was "containing"?